# Image to fit inside a div properly

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to get an image to fit inside my `div` perfectly but a lot of it is missing. It there a way to make it fit correctly. Thanks

Here is how I have it now:

```css
.add {
background-image: url(https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/images/SPCA-Header-Images-Blue.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: 100%;
height: 100%;   
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 19px;
font-weight: 300;
padding: 40px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="add">
text
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make the `div` grow to fit the picture?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to *fill* the whole div (with parts of it possibly being cut off), use `background-size: cover`

If you want the *whole*  image to be shown in all possible proportions of the div (with parts of the div not being filled by the background image), use `background-size: contain;`.

If you want the whole `div` to be filled by the image and don't care about the image being distorted due to a wrong height/width relation, you can use `background-size: 100% 100%;` (which is usually a bad idea for photos and only works for abstract graphics)

If you want the whole image to be shown without being cut off and without empty spaces in the DIV, you need to give the DIV `width` and `height` settings that reflect the original height/width proportion of the image.

Comment: How do I make the width if its the width of the screen. Thanks

Comment: My div is 200px high and width 100%.

Comment: Then use the `vw` unit for the height. If for example your image is 1000x750px large, 1000px equals 100vw, so the width has to be 75vw. But of course you have to apply the ratio of your own image in this calculation.